# SSRS: How to disable a parameter (nvarchar) based on another parameter

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

Im making a report that has a parameter
DateFrom:
Date To:
Handled: Successful or Unsuccessful
GroupName:
AgentNamme:

What I want to do is if I selected in Handle 'Unsuccessful' the GroupName will be disabled. I tried looking for answers on the net but failed.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I think you can achieve this using Optional Parameter feature of SSRS.
or you can change the data set in such a way. you can edit the query and check there.

[Example- Optional Parameter](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3453/sql-server-reporting-services-reports-with-optional-query-parameters/)

Comment: Thou your provided link is good. But It is not the perfect fit for my project because I need the textbox to allow multiple values too.

Comment: I don't get what you are trying to achieve.. can you explain

Answer (score 0):

You can't disable a parameter in SSRS.  You have to provide a placeholder value to it instead, usually a null value.

The available values for GroupName should be based on a query to get all of the possible group values, unioned with a null value for N/A.  When Handled = Unsuccessful, the only possible value for GroupName should be N/A.

Comment: is there a possible way to set the default value of groupName = N/A when Handled = Unsuccessful is selected?

Answer (score 0):

Since its impossible to disable a parameter I just query a default value if Hanled=Unsuccessful.